# Get first N key pairs from an Ordered Dictionary to another one

Tags: python, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I have an ordered dictionary (`OrderedDict`) sorted by value. How can I get the top (say 25) key values and add them to a new dictionary?
For example: I have something like this:

```
dictionary={'a':10,'b':20,'c':30,'d':5}
ordered=OrderedDict(sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda x: x[1],reverse=True))
```

Now `ordered` is an ordered dictionary, I want to create a dictionary, say by taking the top 2 most-frequent items and their keys:

```
frequent={'c':30,'b':20}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The primary purpose of [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects) is retaining the order in which the elements were *inserted*.
What you want here is [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#counter-objects), which has the n-most-frequent functionality built-in:

```
>>> dictionary={'a':10,'b':20,'c':30,'d':5}
>>> import collections
>>> collections.Counter(dictionary).most_common(2)
[('c', 30), ('b', 20)]
```

Answer (score 6):

Just make a new dictionary using the first N items (key pairs) in the (reverse) ordered dictionary you already have. For example, to get the top three items you could do something like this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from operator import itemgetter

# create dictionary you have
dictionary = {'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'c': 30, 'd': 5}
ordered = OrderedDict(sorted(dictionary.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True))

topthree = dict(ordered.items()[:3])
print(topthree) # -> {'a': 10, 'c': 30, 'b': 20}
```

For Python 3 one could use `dict(list(ordered.items())[:3])` since `items()` returns an iterator in that version. Alternatively you could use `dict(itertools.islice(ordered.items(), 3))` which would work in both Python 2 and 3.

Also note the result is just a regular dictionary—as you specified in your question—not a `collections.Counter` or other type of mapping. This approach is very general and doesn't require the original `dictionary` to have integer values—just things can be ordered (i.e. compared via the `key` function).

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried indexing the List of tuples from the sorted to get the top nth most frequent items and their keys?
For example, if you need the top 2 most frequent items, you might do

```
dictionary={'a':10,'b':20,'c':30,'d':5}
ordered=dict(sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda x: x[1],reverse=True)[:2])
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the iterator of the items from `ordered.iteritems()` method.

Now, to take the first N items, you may use `islice` method from `itertools`.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> toptwo = itertools.islice(ordered.iteritems(), 2)
>>> list(toptwo)
[('c', 30), ('b', 20)]
>>>
```