# Sort entries of dictionary in decreasing order and print first n entries

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get first N key pairs from an Ordered Dictionary to another one in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287000/get-first-n-key-pairs-from-an-ordered-dictionary-to-another-one-in-python)

I have a large dictionary. How do I sort those entries in decreasing order and then print the first n items? To print the sorted items in dictionary, I am using this code:

```
print sorted(mydictionary.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

Comment: So basically you're asking how to take the `n` first items from a list? And you researched and couldn't find anything?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287000/get-first-n-key-pairs-from-an-ordered-dictionary-to-another-one-in-python...Just found this is a duplicate post, please delete this post. I am not able to. Thanks

Comment: @JustinCarrey It's not quite the same, that one's about `OrderedDict`... (though perhaps it's the duplicate of another question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can print a slice then:

```
print sorted(mydictionary.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:10]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`heapq.nlargest`](http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest):

```
import heapq
print heapq.nlargest(n, mydictionary.iteritems())
```

*Usually this is about the same efficiency-wise (as sorting then slicing), but for very large dictionaries and small `n` it's slightly faster (analysis to follow).* It has the benefit of  being easy to read!

Comment: +1 for `heapq.nlargest` -- but I imagine for small dictionaries, sorting would actually be faster, since timsort is so heavily optimized. I'd love to see some timings for this showing when `nlargest` overtakes timsort + slicing.

Comment: OP does say in the question "large dictionary"... I'll try and update with some timings later, for >10000 dictionaries and small n it seems (marginally) faster, but they're much of a muchness. However, it's always more readable!